# Variable stops queueing data within .each() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a user dashboard in my view, here is the code :

```
UsuariosAB: function (EmID, FiID, Query) {
        if (Query.length == 0) {
            Query = "EmID=" + EmID + "&FiID=" + FiID;
        };
        var DataForm = JSON.stringify("x=0&" + Query);
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/GetUsuariosAB",
            data: DataForm,
            success: function (jqXHR) {
                var html = "";
                var lines = '';
                var EmpresaID_A = 0, FilialID_A = 0;

                $(jqXHR).each(function (i) {

                    if (jqXHR[i].FilialID != 0 && jqXHR[i].ParcelasEmAberto >= 11) {                           
                        lines += '<tr><td class="text-left">' + jqXHR[i].Usuario + '</td><td><a href="#" id="' + jqXHR[i].UsuarioID + '" class="btn btn-delete btn-xs" title="Mover"><span id="naoconvertido" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td><td>' + jqXHR[i].ParcelasEmAberto + '</td></tr>'

                    }
                    if (jqXHR[i].EmpresaID != EmpresaID_A || jqXHR.length == 1) {                            
                        html = '<table class="table table-striped">' +
                            '<thead>' +
                            '<tr><th colspan="3" class="text-center">' + ((jqXHR[0].EmpresalID != 0) ? jqXHR[0].EmpresaID + ' - ' + jqXHR[0].Empresa : jqXHR[0].EmpresaID + ' - ' + jqXHR[0].Empresa) + '</th></tr >' +
                            '</thead >' +
                            '<tbody>'
                    };

                    if (jqXHR[i].FilialID > 0 && (FilialID_A == 0 || FilialID_A != jqXHR[i].FilialID)) {                           

                        html += '' +
                            '<tr><td colspan="3" class="text-center">' + jqXHR[i].FilialID + ' - ' + jqXHR[i].Filial + '</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td class="text - center">User</td><td>Action</td><td>Parcelas em Aberto</td></tr>';
                        FilialID = 0;

                    };

                    html += lines;

                    lines = '';     

                    alert(html);

                    if (jqXHR[i].FilialID == 0) {                            
                        html += '</tbody>' +
                            "</table>";
                    };

                    EmpresaID_A = jqXHR[i].EmpresaID;
                    FilialID_A = jqXHR[i].FilialID;


                });

                alert(html);    

                html = (html.length == 0) ? "<h4>No Results.</h4>" : html;
                $(".usuariosab .home-content .modal-body").html(html);

                $(".btn-delete").on("click", function () {                       
                    var UsID = this.id;
                    var checkstr = confirm('Remove?');
                    if (checkstr == true) {
                        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                    };
                    return false;
                }); 
                $(".usuariosab").show();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $(".usuariosab .home-content .modal-body").html("<h4>Erro: " + errorThrown + "</h4>");
                $(".usuariosab").show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Since I'm not accomplishing my goal I put two alert statements to go along the process, the first one (within the each loop) would show me how the dashboard DOM is being built and I noticed that for some reason after a while the variable *lines* was not queueing my desired data and I get stuck with this sample of code :

```
<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th colspan="3" class="text-center">1 - TITLE</th></tr ></thead ><tbody><tr><td colspan="3" class="text-center">1 - TITLE A</td></tr><tr><td class="text - center">User</td><td>Action</td><td>Parcelas em Aberto</td></tr><tr><td class="text-left">USER 1</td><td><a href="#" id="14" class="btn btn-delete btn-xs" title="Mover"><span id="naoconvertido" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td><td>12</td></tr>
```

Note that this sample is reduced, actually I'm able to queue more users than this.

Then I'm getting this in the second alert statement :

```
<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th colspan="3" class="text-center">1 - TITLE</th></tr ></thead ><tbody></tbody></table>
```

I really do not know why this is happening, can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you create a new table, you clear up everything that was done previously

```
html = '<table class="table table-striped">' +
```

You might want to append

```
html += '<table class="table table-striped">' +
```

With all of this, I think you might want to look a partial views. Your controller could just return the html from the partial view and then you just need to display it. You wouldn't need to build everything up manually with javascript.